# Webrtc integrated play RTSP

Tags: rational-team-concert

I am testing Webrtc-streamer to play RTSP video streams;

The RSTP video stream of live video can be played normally, and the video stream address is as follows:
"rtsp://admin:tww001218@192.168.105.150:554/dac/realplay/2E691C9D-2E85-4A70-9CBA-482CF5461F9C1/MAIN/TCP?streamform=rtp"

However, the RSTP video stream that plays the video playback cannot be played normally, and the video stream address is as follows:
"rtsp://admin:tww001218@192.168.105.150:554/dac/playback/camera/2E691C9D-2E85-4A70-9CBA-482CF5461F9C1/MAIN/TCP?starttime=20240217T050658Z&endtime=20240217T061853Z&name=00000004992000000&size=1064651716&streamform=rtp"

```
<script>
   
   let url = {
   video: "JTHIK1",
   video1: "JTHIK2",
   video2: "JTHIK3",
   video3: "JTHIK4",   
   video4: "JTHIK5",
   video5: "JTHIK6",
   video6: "JTHIK7",
   video7: "JTHIK8",
   };
        let options = "rtptransport=tcp";
        window.onload         = function() {        
        
            this.webRtcServer = new WebRtcStreamer("video", "http://192.168.105.32:8000");
        this.webRtcServer6 = new WebRtcStreamer("video6", "http://192.168.105.32:8000");
            webRtcServer.connect(url.video, null, options);   
      webRtcServer6.connect("rtsp://admin:tww001218@192.168.105.150:554/dac/playback/camera/2E691C9D-2E85-4A70-9CBA-482CF5461F9C1/MAIN/TCP?starttime=20240217T050658Z&endtime=20240217T061853Z&name=00000004992000000&size=1064651716&streamform=rtp");

        }
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
             this.webRtcServer.disconnect();
         this.webRtcServer6.disconnect();
            }

 
</script>
```

[Webrtc-streamer prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maWEX.png)
[Stuck picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re1T6.png)

I want to know what is wrong and how should I fix it,
All RTSP links are playable in VLC ;